# Difference between functional cast notation T(x) and static_cast<T>(x)

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, static-cast

(I know this is very similar to some other questions on here, but I haven't found any that specifically, language-lawyerly, answer *this precise detail*. Most of the near-duplicates are just asking whether they should use `static_cast` over functional-style casts (answer: yes), or the difference between `static_cast` and *C-style* casts.)

In C++, the following two casts appear to be very similar:

```
template<class T, class U> auto convert1(U&& u) {
    return T( std::forward<U>(u) );
}

template<class T, class U> auto convert2(U&& u) {
    return static_cast<T>( std::forward<U>(u) );
}
```

Is there *any* difference for any types `T`, `U`; or are they 100% identical in effect?

If they are different, I'd appreciate some examples of places in the Standard Library where the subtle difference is relevant. (I mean like how `std::make_shared<T>(args...)` is specified to construct its object with `T(args...)` instead of `T{args...}` because of the subtle difference between `T()` and `T{}` there.)

Comment: P.S.: no need to comment that `T(u,v)` works and `static_cast<T>(u,v)` doesn't. I'm asking about a single argument `u` only. :)

Comment: Technically, T(std::forward(u)) is a call to a constructor, not a cast.

Comment: @Justin: At least the top-voted answer there mentions functional-style casts, but unfortunately it doesn't say anything about their semantics; it just says "they exist" and moves on. The *questioner* over there didn't care about functional-style casts.

Comment: You may enjoy reading this: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/style-and-techniques#static-cast

Comment: @Quuxplusone "The questioner over there didn't care about functional-style casts." False. Did you even read that question? On the bullet point list are C-style casts *and* function-style casts

Comment: @Quuxplusone Also, the top voted answer there implies, but didn't explicitly say, that function-style casts are equivalent to C-style casts. It's pretty clear that that was meant.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/style-and-techniques#static-cast talks specifically about `static_cast` versus C-style casts. FWIW, obviously I agree with their style recommendations in this area. I'm just asking the language-lawyer question here.

Comment: @Quuxplusone and *I* was just passing by and posting a comment with a somewhat relevant link I thought you might enjoy reading :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The functional-style cast notation `T(x)` for a single argument is defined by the standard to be identical to the C-style cast notation `(T)x`. The C-style cast notation can do any conversion that `static_cast` can do, and others (which may be undesired), such as casting away constness. So for example `convert1` could be used to convert `int const*` to `int*` while `convert2` could not.

Comment: Ah, yes. [expr.type.conv] "If the initializer is a parenthesized single expression, the type conversion expression is equivalent (in definedness, and if defined in meaning) to the corresponding cast expression." That seems pretty definite. Thanks!

Comment: "and others" also includes `reinterpret_cast` which would certainly not be desired

Comment: I had not realised this before. It's horrifying. I am now concerned that any constructor I have ever written in the form `auto x = Y(z)` is a time-bomb.